# How to use the isspace function in c++?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to figure out how to use this function. I found it on the web and apparently it checks if you have a space in your string. So it's not working out for me. I've figured out that I'm not even getting into the if statement that I need to.

```
for (i=0;i < marks.length();i++)
{
    if (isdigit(marks[i]))
    {
        floatMARK = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        charMARK = 1;
    }
}

if (floatMARK == 1)
{
    printf("were in.");
    for (i=0;i < marks.length();i++)
    {
        if (isspace(marks[i]))
        {
            multiMARK = 1;
            printf("WE HAVE A SPACE!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? If you need me to clarify anything, let me know.

Comment: My mistake. Thank's for catching that, I didn't obviously haha.

Comment: I don't understand why I have -2? 
What have I done wrong D:?

Comment: ¤ As long as you are assuming a restriction to the English alphabet (if you are), I don't see anything *technically* wrong. However, using integers as boolean flags, instead of just using C++ `bool` variables, and e.g. using `printf` instead of C++ iostreams (in a beginner's program), seems to indicate that you have the burden of having first learned C. And if so, then you need to focus on unlearning C, and learning C++, which is a *different language*. Oh, by the way, could it be that you tested the code with input that didn't have digits? Then space would not be detected. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach Thanks for all the information. Makes sense about the voting system. And yes, I have learned C first (through school) and now I am in C++, which is the semester. This is our first assignment (well a part of it) and it is quite confusing. Techinically, we havn't learned any of this "isspace" or "isdigit" stuff, this is me googling ahead and finding this things. I'll take your advice and try and "unlearn c" when learning C++. (:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All that is very unnecessary to just test if a string has a space in it. This is all you need:

```
#include <ctype.h>

bool hasspace = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isspace) != str.end();
```

`::` is the scope resolution operator specifying that `isspace` is a global function, not the similarly-named `std::isspace`, and `find_if` is a function inside `std::`. If you use `using namespace std;` then you don't need `std::` but you do still need the plain `::`.

The `find_if` function takes an iterator to the beginning of the string, an iterator to the end of the string, and a function that takes an argument and returns some value convertible to a `bool`. `find_if` iterates from the first iterator to the second iterator, passing each value of the current item to the function you gave it, and if the function returns `true`, `find_if` returns the iterator that caused the function to return `true`. If `find_if` goes through to the end and the function never returns `true`, then it returns an iterator to the end of the range, which in this case is `str.end()`.

That means that if `find_if` returns `str.end()`, it got to the end of the string without `isspace` returning `true`, which means there was no space characters in the string. Therefore, you can test the result of `find_if` against `str.end()`; If they are unequal (`!=`), that means there was a space in the string, and `hasspace` is `true`. Else, `hasspace` is `false`.

Comment: See now that. What you told me was way to complicated and what you just showed me is "easier" looks hella more complicated to me. I don't even understand whats going. First of, what does "::" do? Second, I don't understand what "std::string::npos;" is doing, or whats going on in their (considering I don't know what :: does).

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn thanks for catching that, that one always confuses me.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, that's what I meant, fixed

Comment: @Robsta: I think it's seriously time you sat down with a good C++ book before resuming this problem. Trust me, you'll do yourself a huge favour.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: No time to do that. Got this assignment due in a few hours. Must complete.

Comment: @Robsta then this should be tagged homework. Read the updated answer for an explanation of the code.

Comment: @SethCarnegie my mistake. Didn't know I could tag homework in here. Learned a bunch of new stuff it seems haha. 
Well. I'm glad you showed me that, but out of curiosity, why wasn't my isspace working?

Comment: @Robsta you're only checking for spaces if the string has digits in it.

Comment: -1: This will not compile because `std::isspace` is a template name (§22.3.3.1/1). You need `::isspace` from `<ctype.h>`, which is ugly because it is in the global namespace, or you need to take `std::isspace<char>` and `std::bind` a `std::locale` object to it, which is a pain.

Comment: @Potatoswatter thanks, fixed, my mistake, I forgot the `<char>`. For things like this, feel free to edit my answer directly.

Comment: @Seth: sorry, my (pre-edit) correction was still incorrect. The template is actually just overloading the function you want to use… specifying `<char>` just gets you to the wrong place. I'll edit to use my other suggestion, but really it's not so clear-cut.

Comment: The problem with the C `issspace()` function is that "the argument is an **int**, the value of which shall be representable as an **unsigned char** or shall equal the value of the macro **EOF**. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."  If plain `char` is signed, then a string could contain negative values.  You need to convert the value to `unsigned char` before passing it to `isspace()`.  (Some implementations handle this, but you shouldn't depend on it.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I've asked related question: [what does “representable” mean in C11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25776824/4279)

Answer (score 0):

> here is another way, if the above version seems strange, or it's above your knowledge

```
if(marks[i] == ' ') {
cout<<"Space found!";
}
```

Comment: That's not equivalent.  `isspace()` checks whether its argument is any whitespace character; that includes the space character as well as `'\f'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'`, and `'\v'` (and possibly others, depending on the locale).