# Is it safe to cast a character type to an integer type

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    char ch = 'a';
    int x;
    x = ch; 
    printf("x=%c", x);
}
```

Is this code safe to use (considering endiness of machine)?

Comment: considering that int is usually bigger than char, I would say yes.

Comment: Note that `char` *is* "an integer type".

Comment: my actual programm is doing something like:

int getchoice(.........)//plz ignore arguments type
int main()
{
-----------
------------
printf("u hv chosen:%c",getchoice);
-----------
}

int getchoice(------)
{
int slected;
----------
---------
slected=getchar();
------
------
return slected;
}

Comment: character literals are always of type int in C, so you the cast is redundant

Comment: Do not edit your question after getting answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to cast a character (like `char`) type to an integer type (like `int`).

In this answer and others, endian-ness is not a factor.

There are 4 conversions going on here and no casting:

1. `a` is character of the C encoding.  `'a'` converts to an `int` at compile time.

   ```
   'a'
   ```
2. The `int` is converted to a `char`.

   ```
   char ch = 'a';
   ```
3. The `char ch` is converted to an `int x`.  In *theory* there could be a loss of data going from `char` to `int` **, but given the overwhelming implementations, there is none.  Typical examples: If `char` is signed in the range -128 to 127, this maps well into `int`. If `char` is unsigned in the range 0 to 255, this also maps well into `int`.

   ```
   int x;
   x = ch;
   ```
4. `printf("%c", x)` uses the `int x` value passed to it, converts it to `unsigned char` and then prints that character.  (C11dr §7.21.6.1 8 @haccks) Note there is no conversion of `x` due to the usual conversion of variadic parameters as `x` is all ready an `int`.

   ```
   printf("x=%c", x);
   ```

---

** `char` and `int` could be the same size and `char` is unsigned with a positive range more than `int`.  This is the one potential problem with casting `char` to `int` although typically there is not loss of data.  This *could* be further complicated should `char` have range like 0 to 2³²-1 and `int` with a range of -(2³¹-1) to +(2³¹-1).  I know of no such machine.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `ch` is an `unsigned char`.

Comment: `INT_MAX < CHAR_MAX` is strange (on a hosted implementation). Could I print a `char` with `printf` and `%c` on this platform? `%c` expects an `int`... While there may be reasons to have `int` and `char` with the same size on some machine, I don't see a reason why `char` should be unsigned there.

Comment: @haccks: I think that's meant to read "...and `char` could be unsigned..."

Comment: @mafso; OK. Its time to delete my answer.

Comment: @mafso Thanks for the correction. The last paragraph should be -(power(2,31) -1) to power(2,31)-1 and not using 32 as earlier posted.  This is intentionally one different than your suggestion of `-power(2,31)` given that odd-ball machine may use one's complement or sign-magnitude integers.

Comment: @mafso My concern about `INT_MAX < CHAR_MAX` stems from a post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25776962/2410359  Agree such a machine would be quite esoteric.

Comment: Thanks for the link; My thoughts that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)` implies `char` being signed (on a hosted implementation) came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation, taking `printf("%c")` into account, additionally to `fputc`/`fgetc`.

Comment: FYI, on a 2's complement machine, the value with all bits 0 but the sign bit, may trap (that is, `INT_MIN` may be `-INT_MAX`).

Comment: @mafso   Certainly thought `INT_MIN` had to be `-INT_MAX  - 1` in 2's complement.  Found this ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Most_negative_number  Do you have any ref that supports the "may trap" option for C?  or is that a question for SO?

Comment: C11 6.2.6.2 p2 "Which of these [sign and magnitude, two's complement, ones' complement] applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), [...], is a trap representation or a normal value." Don't know if that exists, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, casting integer types to bigger integer types is always safe.

Standard library's `*getc` (fgetc, getchar, ...) functions do just that--they read `unsigned chars` internally and cast them to `int` because `int` provides additional room for encoding EOF (end of file, usually EOF==-1).

Comment: thank you.
 but what happens in the statement ch2=x;  ch2 will store least significant byte or most significant byte .  ch2 is 0 or 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, because `int` is bigger than `char`, but using `char` instead of `int` would not be safe for the same reason.

Comment: Note: C does not specify `int` is bigger than `char`.  `CHAR_MAX` may greater than `INT_MAX`.  Consider if `int` and `char` the same size and `char` is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

it is safe here because `char` is converted to `int` anyway when calling `printf`.

see [C++ variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is first =

`int x = ch` => Assigning the ascii value of the char to an int

And finally : 
`printf("x=%c", x);` => Printing the ascii value as a char, which will print the actual char that correspond to that value.  So yeah it's safe to do that, it's a totally predicatable behaviour.
But safe does not mean useful as integer is bigger than char, usually we do the inverse to save some memory.

Comment: It's highly doubtful that ASCII is the character set and encoding; more likely Windows-1252 or similar, IBM437, or UTF-8.