# Does isspace() accept getchar() values?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

[`isspace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) works if the input is [representable as `unsigned char`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25776824/4279) or equal to `EOF`.

[`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) reads the next character from stdin.

When `getchar()!=EOF`; are all `getchar()` returned values representable as `unsigned char`?

```
uintmax_t count_space = 0;
for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF; )
  if (isspace(c))
    ++count_space;
```

May this code lead to the undefined behavior?

Comment: All the ctype.h functions were designed so that they could deal with input that could be either a character or `EOF`. From the C rationale: "Since these functions are often used primarily as macros, their domain is restricted to the small
positive integers representable in an unsigned char, plus the value of EOF."

Comment: @Lundin `isspace(CHAR_MIN)` is undefined on some platforms ([follow the link in the question or   in the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25776824/4279)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to C11 [WG14 draft version N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **§7.21.7.6/2** The `getchar` function is equivalent to `getc` with the argument stdin.
>
> **§7.21.7.5/2** The `getc` function is equivalent to `fgetc`...
>
> **§7.21.7.1/2** [`!=EOF` case] ...the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`...<sub>text in [...] is mine.</sub>

i.e.,

- `isspace()` accepts `getchar()` values
- all `getchar()!=EOF` values are representable as `unsigned char`
- there is no undefined behavior here.

If you think it is too obvious ("what else can it be"), think again. For example, in [the related case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25776824/4279): `isspace(CHAR_MIN)` may be undefined i.e., it may be undefined behavior to pass a character to a character classification function!

If `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` the result may be implementation-defined:

> **§6.3.1.3/3** Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: So come back to your point about `CHAR_MIN`. It seems to me that this is always undefined, because negative values can never be represented as `unsigned char`, only converted to them. The noticeble exception being the case were `CHAR_MIN` would be `EOF`.

Comment: @JensGustedt CHAR_MIN may be 0 on some platforms.

Comment: Yes, but the interesting case being `CHAR_MIN` being negative. Or stated otherwise, all these functions are only defined for positive `char` values plus an exception for `EOF`. And all values of the execution character set have non-negative values.

Comment: you said *"this is **always** undefined"* [emphasis mine]. I said: *"CHAR_MIN may be 0 on some platforms."* i.e., the behavior is NOT undefined on such platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `getchar()` is of the same format as `fgetc()`. C11 defines the return value of `fgetc()` in [7.21.7.1p2-3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1p2):

> 2. If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined).
>
> **Returns**
>
> 3. If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end- of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the `fgetc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. [289]

Since this is an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`, the `int` will *almost* always have the same value as the unsigned char.

It might not be true for high values on some platforms where `sizeof(int) == 1`; these however are mostly DSP platforms, so it is almost certain that character classification is not needed on these platforms.

---

The `is*` functions are carefully defined so that they can be used directly with the return value of `*getc*` [C11 7.4p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1):

> 1 The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. [198] In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or **shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`**. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

i.e. it is legal to even pass `EOF` to the `is*` functions. Of course `isanything(EOF)` will always return 0, therefore to count *continuous* whitespace characters one could simply use something like:

```
while (isspace(getchar())) space_count ++;
```

However, signed char values are not OK, and for example MSVC C debug library is known to *abort* if a negative value other than `EOF` is passed in to any of the character classification functions.

Comment: the questions says explicitly: "isspace() works if ... **or equal to EOF.**" EOF is not the problem here.

Comment: note: the code in the question counts the number of spaces until EOF is returned. Your code counts until the first non-space character. It is not the same.

Comment: @jfs *note* that is exactly why I have put the word *continuous* in italics.

Comment: the code in my question does not count *continuous* whitespace. It counts all of it.