# C programming preferring uint8 over char

Tags: c

The code I am handling has a lot of castings that are being made from `uint8` to `char`, and then the C library functions are called upon this castings.I was trying to understand why would the writer prefer `uint8` over `char`.
For example:

```
uint8 *my_string = "XYZ";
strlen((char*)my_string);
```

What happens to the `\0`, is it added when I cast?

What happens when I cast the other way around?

Is this a legit way to work, and why would anybody prefer working with `uint8` over `char`?

Comment: Use `char` for characters, `uint8_t` if you **mean** "integer value". But there is no type `uint8`. Don't use homebrew types if there are standard ones, see `stdint.h`!

Comment: The `\0` is part of the string literal. `"XYZ"` means `(char []){ 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\0' }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The casts `char <=> uint8` are fine. It is always allowed to access any defined memory as unsigned characters, including string literals, and then of course to  cast a pointer that points to a string literal back to `char *`.

In

```
uint8 *my_string = "XYZ";
```

`"XYZ"` is an anonymous array of 4 `char`s - including the terminating zero. This decays into a pointer to the first character. This is then implicitly converted to `uint8 *` - strictly speaking, it should have an explicit cast though.

---

The problem with the type `char` is that the standard leaves it up to the implementation to define whether it is signed or unsigned. If there is lots of arithmetic with the characters/bytes, it might be beneficial to have them unsigned by default.

A particularly notorious example is the `<ctype.h>` with its `is*` character class functions - `isspace`, `isalpha` and the like. They require the characters as [**`unsigned char`s** (converted to int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119083/does-isspace-accept-getchar-values)! A piece of code that does the equivalent of `char c = something(); if (isspace(c)) { ... }` is not portable and a compiler cannot even warn about this! If the `char` type is signed on the platform (default on x86!) and the character  isn't ASCII (or, more properly, a member of the basic execution character set), then the behaviour is undefined - [it would even abort on MSVC debug builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693654/isalpha-giving-an-assertion), but unfortunately just causes silent undefined behaviour (array access out of bounds) on glibc.

However, a compiler would be very loud about using `unsigned char *` or its alias as an argument to `strlen`, hence the cast.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation saying the "is*" functions need unsigned char? The man pages I have say "int".

Comment: @coredump yea added a link - they're unsigned chars converted to `int` + `EOF`, just the same values as `getchar()` would return

Comment: As long you use `char` you are fine for characters. It has to be able to represent all characters of the target character set by definition. The example above better had used `char` from the start - actually `const char` to avoid any problems trying to write to the string literal accidentally..Interestingly, the string functions interpret the passed `char` arguments (resp. the pointers' targets) as `unsigned char` where this would make a difference.

Comment: @Olaf we do know very little about the code - of course the 2 line example should better have used `char` but it didn't need to have a string literal, nor would it need to have used `strlen` either since the return value is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Well, we have to rely on what OP posts is a [mcve] (emphasise the **c**) or at least the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I wasn't much about the string **literal** (that was only the part about using `const`), but an array/pointer for a string in general. The string functions don't make much sense if you don't have some kind of C-string. And the `memXXX` functions take a `void *`).

Comment: It is indeed quite unfortunate that so many systems use signed `char` by default. It makes the C library semantics inconsistent. `isalpha` and friends, `tolower`, `toupper`, but also `strcmp`, `getchar`... all use unsigned char values, a very often overlooked fact even by expert C programmers. Kudos for pointing this out.

Comment: And signed char makes the `char ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) {...}` "work" :(

Comment: @chqrlie: "So many". Most systems seem to be using unsign `char`. But yeah, there is just one `signed char` platform requiredd to mess things up. Not the first, but maybe the last legacy in the C language. It would be really good if the next version of the standard would simply make a clear cut, even at the cost ofd compatibility. Call me a dreamer …

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It doesn't work (as you know), but the likelyness for an (typically) `0xFFU` character code appearing in a string is just low (and it indeed works for people ignoring other than English language like the origin of ASCII..

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: and the fans of French author *Pierre Louÿs*. Note however that `0xFF` is an invalid byte in UTF-8, which is becoming prevalent today...

Comment: @Olaf: *Most systems seem to be using unsigned `char`*? Not really. Most compilers allow the programmer to specify the default signedness of `char`, but the default on x86 is signed, which covers most PCs, laptops and servers. Granted there are even more phones and embedded systems that may have unsigned by default, that is still a good proportion of C code in use today.

Comment: @chqrlie it should probably read "most device units" as in number of processors... ARM <3

Comment: @Olaf: *Call me a dreamer*: I have a vision for this evolution. We could define a subset of the C language where such implementation details are more constrained and many cases of undefined behavior defined (unsigned char by default, two's complement representation for integers, with defined overflow and signed right shift semantics, IEEE representations for floating point...), Some risky library functions removed (`gets`, `strncpy`, `strtok`...), `EOF == -1`, `EXIT_SUCCESS == 0`, a much higher diagnostics level with errors instead of warnings... We should call this **strict C**.

Comment: I agree with everything else except defined signed integer overflow. Whether MAX_INT + 1 = MAX_INT + 1 or MIN_INT, it is a bug already :D

Comment: @chqrlie I'd much rather have a language that aborts on signed integer overflow :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: a program that has integer overflows may indeed be buggy, but defining the behavior one way or another removes the opportunity for the compiler to perform counter-intuitive optimisations. Trapping on overflow may not be feasible at minimal cost on many architectures, wrap around is the de facto standard behavior on two's complement architectures.

Comment: @chqrlie The counter-intuitive optimizations come from the fact that people assume that if something is possible in the assembly on an architecture, then the C compiler must implement it that way. There is nothing counter-intuitive if people don't assume this, or if not know assembly. C.f. aligned/unaligned access. [BTW, for further discussion we do have the C chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c)...

Comment: @chqrlie, Antti: To complete the nastiness: We concentrated on `0xFF`, but actually `EOF` is not required to be `-1`, just negative. Which will make all non-ASCII characters problematic (or >7 bit non-ASCII-based encodings).

Comment: @chqrlie: By "most systems" I mean the standard ABI. Compilers are flexible, but most platforms require a certain behaviour for interoperability e.g. with the standard library and others. ARM ABIs for instance do simply becahuse early ARMs lacked some sign-extend loads IIRC, so they used `unsigned char` from the early days on. And that's one of the most used platforms wich decades more devices than e.g. x86. To complete that I just had to check 8051 which I assume also uses unsigned `char`s. Those two are the vast majority of systems already.

Comment: @chqrlie: As am embedded developer, while I'm not happy about UB, I don't see how this can be avoided without major degradation in code performance and increased size on common CPUs which don't support e.g. hardware address range verification for each access. Btw: `gets` **is not** part of the standard since 7 years now.

Comment: @Olaf: Of course `gets` has been removed from the standard, but C compilers still routinely accept it and C libraries have it for compatibility reasons. If compiling in *strict C*  mode, this function would be forbidden. I am not advocating a *safe* version of the language that has costly check at runtime, just a few semantical changes that make certain undefined expressions defined, such as `-1 >> 1`.

Comment: @chqrlie: This is clearly no way related to the compiler, but of the library only. Said that, the MS libc even warns about safe functions just to promote their non-standard stuff. This does not really help beginners trust the standard. Said that: on typical freestanding environments there is no stdlib, maybe except for functions required by the compiler to implement the normal operators (`memcpy`, etc. namely, gcc is a good example here). Your example is exactly bad to support your position. Many smaller CPUs don't have a signed shift right instruction.